# How do I pass arguments to after_request?

Tags: python, flask

I am new to Flask and am learning about the `@app.after_request` and `@app.teardown_appcontext`. I have a [decorated view](https://github.com/lepture/example-oauth2-server/blob/master/app.py#l246-250) for oauthlib that takes an argument, `data` (which is an object).

```
@app.route('/api/me')
@oauth.require_oauth()
def me(data):
    user = data.user
    return jsonify(username=user.username)
```

After this view (and many other views) are executed, I'd like to update my database but need to have access to the variable `data`. How do I do that with `@app.after_request` or `@app.teardown_appcontext`?

```
@app.after_request
def record_ip(response):
   client = data.client # needs access to "data"
   .... log stuff in my database ...
   return response
```

Comment: Doesn't the [global `request` object](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.request) work? `from flask import request`

Comment: @LukasGraf: The global `request` object is not the same thing here; see the [documentation on that decorator](https://flask-oauthlib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/oauth1.html#protect-resource).

Comment: @MartijnPieters yeah, I just realized that while reading your answer. I somehow skipped over the oauth part.

Comment: Sorry @LukasGraf, I should have called it something else, like data. I'll update the question so as to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add the object to the [`flask.g` globals object](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.g):

```
from flask import g

@app.route('/api/me')
@oauth.require_oauth()
def me(req):
    user = req.user
    g.oauth_request = req
    return jsonify(username=user.username)

@app.after_request
def record_ip(response):
   req = g.get('oauth_request')
   if req is not None:
       client = req.client # needs access to "req"
       # .... log stuff in my database ...

   return response
```

The global `flask.g` context is thread safe and tied to the current request; quoting from the [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/appcontext/#locality-of-the-context):

> The application context is created and destroyed as necessary. **It never moves between threads and it will not be shared between requests.**